# Большая задержка после ввода команд aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу телеграмм бота на aiogram,

При первом запуске бота все работает просто идеально, а вот при втором очень большая задержка после ввода команд, а то и вообще не выводит сообщение. Приходится создавать нового бота, помогите пожалуйста) код - ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Executor, Types
from modules.config import token


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher=(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: пожалуйста дайте код текстом а не картинкой

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/quick_start.html - код взят от сюда

Comment: может проблема в вашем config файле? если токен задать просто в коде с ботом останется такое же поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Трабл был в брандмауэре Windows Defender.

Answer (score 0):

Не удаётся воспроизвести проблему.
Данный код работает быстро, сколько не запускал.

Возможны проблемы:

- с вашим интернет-соединением
- с вашим компьютером
- с вашим телеграм-клиентом

Попробуйте запускать бота в других условиях.
Например сервер, арендованный где-нибудь в Амстердаме, даст возможность убедиться, что проблема не в коде.